# iPhone ModalViewController For Table View Open by Button?

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

App Description: I have a UIWebview and a Toolbar beneath it. A button on the toolbar should bring up a modal table view, but it does not.

The toolbar has four buttons:

Previous: Goes to previous site

Next: Goes to the next site (these two being different than the default goForward and goBack methods)

Menu: Display a modalViewController with a TableView of all the available sites (sites will be limited to an array of site links that the next and previous buttons cycle through)

Refresh: Refreshes current site

**Application has four main classes/files**

WebAppDelegate.h and .m

ListViewController.h and .m (which has the Table View in its xib and the code to fill the table in the .m/ be the modal view controller)

**There is only one warning and no errors.**

Warning: 'WebAppDelegate' may not repsond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'

**When I run the program, everything is fine until I click the Menu button. I receive this runtime error**

```
[WebAppDelegate presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

**Below is the code for the Menu button, which is currently in WebAppDelegate.m**

```
-(IBAction)menu:(id)sender {
ListViewController *aListView=[[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self setListController:aListView];
aListView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:aListView animated:YES];
[aListView release];
}
```

Any ideas on what causes the application to crash and why the modal table view does not display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what your problem is - you're sending a selector to an object that doesn't respond to that selector.

```
[self presentModalViewController:aListView animated:YES];
```

`self` in this case in your instance of WebAppDelegate, which is probably a subclass of NSObject, not UIViewController. `presentModalViewController:animated:` is a method on UIViewController, so you need to send that message to whatever view controller is currently displayed (or perhaps a navigation controller) if you want to present another view controller modally.

Do not ignore compiler warnings - the one warning you have is likely telling you that...

```
'WebAppDelegate' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'
```

...which, again, is exactly your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:aListView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Not sure where he insinuates that he has a navigation controller. If anything, I would be willing to bet that he doesn't have one, and it doesn't help to give an answer that could be confusing because it isn't explained fully.

Comment: This worked, and now have a new runtime error (no other compile-time errors or warnings): "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "ListViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"

Something is wrong in the Table View code, but it's at least progressing.

Comment: SBrocket is right in that I do not have a navigation controller. I used self.listController, which might still be the wrong approach.